# Nodejs TypeScript: Property 'email' does not exist on type 'string | object'

Tags: node.js, typescript

TypeScript is giving me the below error in the terminal.

```
  static resendEmail = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const jwtToken = req.body.jwtToken;
    const jwtData = jwt.verify(jwtToken, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    const email = jwtData.email;
    const account = await userModel.findOne({email}).exec();
    console.log(account)
  };
```

jwtData looks like this..

```
{ email: 'me@email.com',
  id: '5d74fc5d900de015a04c2107',
  iat: 1567947869 }
```

The error is `error TS2339: Property 'email' does not exist on type 'string | object'.` the place is `const email = jwtData.email;`

**Edit**

```
  static resendEmail = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    interface JWTData {
      email: string;
      id: string;
    }
    const jwtToken = req.body.jwtToken;
    const jwtData = jwt.verify(jwtToken, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

    const isJWTData = (input: object): input is JWTData => {
      return 'email' in input;
    }
    if (isJWTData(jwtData)) { 
      console.log(jwtData.email)
    }
  };
```

the error is now `Shadowed name: 'jwtData' (no-shadowed-variable)tslint(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type definitions for the [`verify`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/e43e44dc66f97f0cf138ed9f15cb2f798e824fd8/types/jsonwebtoken/index.d.ts#L155-L159) method define the return type as `string | object`. So you're trying to access `email` on `string | object` (which it does not exist).

You have a few options:

- Cast the value and access email (could lead to a runtime error if the types *are* correct)
- Use a type guard (protects against runtime errors)
- Override the types or open a PR to the `@types` package

```js
const jwtData: string | object = { email: "user@example.com" };

jwtData.email; // Invalid

interface JWTData {
  email: string;
}

(jwtData as JWTData).email // Valid

const isJWTData = (input: object | string): input is JWTData => {
  return typeof input === "object" && "email" in input;
};

if (isJWTData(jwtData)) {
  jwtData.email; // Valid
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAVgdygEQIZVQLhtATgSzAHMYAfGEAIzgFNhYBeGAbxhoFtV8AbbAIgCuEGrgACNAB6p2AB240AdKHZ8YAXwDcAWABQuxCnSoFHLtw0wA9JZgBJMADdU3fABNduwlBEAzVMBoYACkAdQAVNAwWXRg2Th5sPEIibR01Dx0ACgNI1BhUCGDw3IBKE3juKxsANWc3DN1QSFh8CFCIoxgmbKRc7CpaehLsHM7Woo6o5hiYXBooAVwwGD5THlVCeF6jVPS9HXwfGEzW9tyewwwSkuidWNGMcrMLaxhal3c0oA)

Overriding the types for `verify` in only your project may look something like this:

```js
declare module "jsonwebtoken" {
  export function verify(
    token: string,
    secretOrPublicKey: string | Buffer,
    options?: VerifyOptions
  ): { email: string };
}

const jwtData = verify("token", "secretOrPublicKey");
const email = jwtData.email;
```

I would be careful casting or modifying the types (unless the types themselves are wrong in which case opening a PR to DefinitelyTyped would be the best options).

The safest route is to use the type guard because it also protects unexpected results at runtime as well.

Comment: I've saved an edit above but maybe I'm getting it wrong still??

Comment: To fix the tslint error with the shadowed variable you can rename the input to something like `const isJWTData = (input: object): input is JWTData => { return email in input }`

Comment: The second problem is that you're not using the type guard properly. It needs to be invoked and nested within an `if` so TypeScript can assign the correct type: `if (isJWTData(jwtData)) { jwtData.email }`

Comment: Read more about type guards here: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html#user-defined-type-guards

Comment: Ive edited the edit again an im now getting `The right-hand side of an 'in' expression must be of type 'any', an object type or a type parameter.ts(2361)`

Comment: Yes, it should be `return "email" in input` since you renamed the argument to `input`

Comment: with this fix im getting the same error on the line `if (isJWTData(jwtData)) { ` seen here https://i.imgur.com/x6cEPdq.png

Comment: Ah, try updating the type guard to be 

`const isJWTData = (input: object | string): input is JWTData => {
  return typeof input === "object" && "email" in input;
};
`